# Can not grant FINE_LOCATION Permission

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-location

Hello I am building an app I would like to access the location of the mobile phone. However it seems that I can not grant the access fine location permission so my app doesn't function in Android M cellphone which I am testing.
Here is a part of my code:

```
 public class LocationMainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ListView listView;
private static final String EXTERNAL_PERMISSIONS[] = new String[]{
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.INTERNET};
private static final int EXTERNAL_CODE=1;
private boolean perm;
private Cursor cursor;
private DatabaseAdapt dbAdapt;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_location_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar4);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.locationContainer);

    dbAdapt = new DatabaseAdapt(this);
    dbAdapt.open();
    cursor =dbAdapt.loadLocationTitles();
    String [] from = new String[]{DatabaseAdapt.LOCATION_TITLE};
    int [] to = new int[] {android.R.id.text1};
    CursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,cursor,
            from,to,0);
    listView.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
}

public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    cursor.close();
    dbAdapt.close();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main,menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if(id==R.id.add_button);{
        askForPerm();
        if(perm){
            Intent intent = new Intent(LocationMainActivity.this,LocationSecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else {
            askForPerm();
        }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void askForPerm () {

    // if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    int w = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    int r = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.INTERNET);

    if (w != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && r != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, EXTERNAL_PERMISSIONS, EXTERNAL_CODE);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Permissions already granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        perm=true;
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode){
        case EXTERNAL_CODE:
            if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,permissions[0])==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                perm=true;
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(this,"Permissions denied",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                perm=false;
            }
            break;
    }
}
}
```

In this activity I ask for the permissions and only then I can add a new location. The app moves to the next activity regularly, the permissions granted toast is shown even I install the app for the first time which seems a little weird. I use the same code to request the Write External and camera permissions in another feature of the app and it is working fine.

I have also included the code of my second activity where I would like to obtain the location coordinates

```
 private EditText editTitleLocation, addressText, latText,longText;
private Button saveLocationButton, deleteLocationButton, navigateButton,findLocationButton;
private static final int UPDATE_TIME = 15000;
private static final int FASTER_UPDATE_TIME = 10000;
private GoogleApiClient myGoogleApi;
private Location location;
private LocationRequest myLocationRequest;
private static final int CHECK_CODE=1;
private double longitude,latitude;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_location_second);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    initializeViews();
    buildGoogleApi();

}

private void initializeViews(){
    editTitleLocation = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTitleLocation);
    addressText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.addressText);
    latText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.latitudeText);
    longText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.longitudeText);
    saveLocationButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.saveLocation);
    deleteLocationButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.deleteLocation);
    findLocationButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.findLocation);
    navigateButton= (Button)findViewById(R.id.navigateLocation);
    saveLocationButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    deleteLocationButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    findLocationButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    navigateButton.setOnClickListener(this);

}

public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    if(myGoogleApi!=null){
        myGoogleApi.connect();
    }
}

public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
   if(myGoogleApi!=null)
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(myGoogleApi,LocationSecondActivity.this);
}

public void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    myGoogleApi.disconnect();
}

private synchronized void buildGoogleApi(){
    myGoogleApi = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
}

private void createRequest (){

    myLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    myLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_TIME)
                    .setFastestInterval(FASTER_UPDATE_TIME)
                    .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder().addLocationRequest(myLocationRequest);
    PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result = LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(myGoogleApi,builder.build());

    result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
            final Status status = result.getStatus();
            switch (status.getStatusCode()){
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                    retrieveLocation();
                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                    try{
                        status.startResolutionForResult(LocationSecondActivity.this,CHECK_CODE);
                    }catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                    Toast.makeText(LocationSecondActivity.this,"Settings Change Unavailable",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
}

private void retrieveLocation(){
    try {
        location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(myGoogleApi);
    }catch (SecurityException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   switch (requestCode){
       case CHECK_CODE:
           switch (requestCode){
               case Activity.RESULT_OK:
               retrieveLocation();
                   break;
               case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                   break;
           }
           break;
   }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    createRequest();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Toast.makeText(this,"Google Api can not connect",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    this.location=location;
    longitude=location.getLongitude();
    latitude=location.getLatitude();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int id = v.getId();

    switch (id){
        case R.id.saveLocation:
            break;
        case R.id.deleteLocation:
            break;
        case R.id.navigateLocation:
            break;
        case R.id.findLocation:

            if(location!=null){
                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                Log.e("MALAKIS",String.valueOf(latitude));
                longitude=location.getLongitude();
                latText.setText(String.valueOf(latitude));
                longText.setText(String.valueOf(longitude));
            }else {
                if(!myGoogleApi.isConnected()){
                    myGoogleApi.connect();
                    Log.e("ELSE","fdsfddsd");
                }
               try {

                   LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(myGoogleApi, myLocationRequest, this);
               }catch (SecurityException ex){
                   ex.printStackTrace();
               }
            }

            break;
    }

}
```

Here  the location is object is null and the security location is triggered pointing that I dont have the fine location permission. So please can someone point me to the right direction? Do I have do ask again for permissions in the second activity?

The log is showing this below:

```
    W/System.err: java.lang.SecurityException: Client must have 
  ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission to request PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY 
 locations.
 05-30 10:50:40.516 32177-32177/com.example.notepad.isidorosioannou.notepad 
 W/System.err:     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1602)
 05-30 10:50:40.516 32177-32177/com.example.notepad.isidorosioannou.notepad 
 W/System.err:     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1555)
 05-30 10:50:40.516 32177-32177/com.example.notepad.isidorosioannou.notepad 
W/System.err:     at 
com.google.android.gms.internal.zzase$zza$zza.zza(Unknown Source)
05-30 10:50:40.516 32177-32177/com.example.notepad.isidorosioannou.notepad 
W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzasg.zza(Unknown 
Source)
05-30 10:50:40.516 32177-32177/com.example.notepad.isidorosioannou.notepad 
W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzash.zza(Unknown 
Source)
05-30 10:50:40.516 32177-32177/com.example.notepad.isidorosioannou.notepad 
W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzary$1.zza(Unknown 
Source)
05-30 10:50:40.516 32177-32177/com.example.notepad.isidorosioannou.notepad 
W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzary$1.zza(Unknown 
Source)
05-30 10:50:40.516 32177-32177/com.example.notepad.isidorosioannou.notepad 
W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaad$zza.zzb(Unknown 
Source)
```

Comment: *the security location is triggered pointing that I dont have the fine location permission* ... is that a runtime exception or IDE/Lint warning ... I bet on warning ... and it has nothing to do with the fact that **getLastLocation may return null and you have to live with that**

Comment: One tiny thing to check on, your <uses-permission> and <permission> elements need to be outside of <application>. They should be immediate children of the root <manifest> element. Sometimes when you put them inside when the app launches the location for instance will already be in use and cause trouble like this.

Comment: I have edited my question and included also the log. the permissions are outside the <application>. I can get the coordinates when testing on Android 5.0 but not in Android 6.0

Comment: what is your targetsdkversion

Comment: 24. I need to request the permission inside the retrieveLocation method and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

put following code in your askForPerm () method:-

```
LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    locationRequest.setInterval(30 * 1000);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5 * 1000);
    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
            .addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
    builder.setAlwaysShow(true); //this is the key ingredient

    PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
            LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(googleApiClient, builder.build());
    result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
            final Status status = result.getStatus();
            final LocationSettingsStates state = result.getLocationSettingsStates();
            switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                    // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize location
                    // requests here.
                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                    // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed by showing the user
                    // a dialog.
                    try {
                        // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                        // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                        status.startResolutionForResult(MainActivity.this, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                        // Ignore the error.
                    }
                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                    // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the
                    // settings so we won't show the dialog.
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
```

Try this!!It works in my application.

Comment: I modified my code and asked the permissions inside the second activity and it works. I wanted to ask also a question. Is it possible to check if the user is connected to wifi or network and prompt him to enable internet connection? Because the settings api that I use it prompts the user only to enable access to his position

Comment: yes you can check with this:-                                                           public boolean isConnected() {
        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Activity.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected())
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }